# How to pick up data from listview and show data in a textbox in C#?

Tags: c#, listview, textbox

**Hi**, How can I get data from list-view and show this data in a Textbox. I have done googling and you-tube enough but exact answer does not matching. Please help me.
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What flavour of .NET are you using?

Comment: I am using windows form of visual studio. I am new in C#. I am trying to learn asp.net gradually. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyTextBox.Text = string.Join(", ",(
    from i in MyListView.SelectedItems
    select i.Text
));
```

That thing on the middle 2 lines is called Linq, it's a cool way to get information from collections like your ListView. You'll need a using statement for System.Linq

I'm making a few assumptions in this example, for instance that you want the selected items in the list, and that they should be separated by a comma and a space. I also don't have a Windows Form project handy to test it with

It's probably not exactly what you want, but it should get you close enough that you can tweak it

Comment: Thanks your comment..But exactly does not matching What I wanted.

Comment: If you want a more specific answer, then you need to be more specific in your question. What data do you want from the ListView? How should it be presented in the text box? Does the text box already exist or does it need creating? Providing an example of the code you've already tried will help us to understand the intent behind your question and give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string dataItemText;
            dataItemText = departmentCodeTextBox.Text;
            string dataNameText;
            dataNameText = departmentNameTextBox.Text;
            ListViewItem findDeptCode = showListView.FindItemWithText(dataItemText);
            ListViewItem findDeptName = showListView.FindItemWithText(dataNameText);
            if (findDeptCode!=null)
            {
               dataNameText = findDeptName.ToString();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("DeparmentCode Does Not Hold");
            }
        }
```

// Here I want to show, if departmentCodeTextBox.Text will be exist in listview then when I click searchButton it will be shown dataNameText in  departmentNameTextBox.Text otherwise it will be shown "DepartmentCode Does not Hold".
My if segmented code does not work
but else segmented code properly work. I think it is wrong way to pick up my Data from listview. If any hesitation pleas notify me.